# Пытаюсь перевести iphone 4s в pwndfu через arduino

Tags: arduino

Кто поможет, пытаюсь перевести iphone 4s в pwndfu через arduino, но ничего не выходит. Arduino atmega328p(неоригинал) and USB HostShield 2.0. Сразу говорю не шарю в arduino. Может нужен оригинальный ардуино?
Вспаяно вот так
[image: USB HostShield 2.0 спаян вот так]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.